# Function that reads an array until 0 is entered

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-allocation

I want to make a program that dynamically allocates memory for each element of an array while it is entered from stdin and stored into an array. The reading should stop when 0 is entered. If I try to make it directly in main(), in looks like this:

```
int *a;
int i = 0;

a = malloc(sizeof(int));

do
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    a = realloc(a, (i + 2) * sizeof(int)); // enough space for storing another number
    i++;

} while (a[i-1] != 0);
```

But I don't know how to make a function that does this. This is what I've tried, but it crashes everytime.

```
void read(int **a, int *cnt)
{
a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*a = malloc(sizeof(int));
*cnt = 0;

do
{
    scanf("%d", a[*cnt]);
    *a = realloc(*a, (*cnt + 2) * sizeof(int)); // enough space for storing another number
    (*cnt)++;

} while (a[*cnt-1] != 0);
```

}

Comment: what if you put your code in a function returning int * and return a from there ?

Comment: I suggest starting with a simpler function first, make a function `foo` that lets you modify an `int` that was defined in `main`

Answer (score 1):

how about putting everything inside a function and returning a;

```
int *read()
{
    int *a;
    int i = 0;

    a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if( !a ) return NULL;

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        a = realloc(a, (i + 2) * sizeof(int)); // enough space for storing another number
        if( !a ) return NULL;
    i++;

    } while (a[i-1] != 0);

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are calling this in the usual way:

```
void read(int **a, int *cnt)
{
a = malloc(sizeof(int)); // This overwrites local a disconnecting it from the main a
*a = malloc(sizeof(int)); // so this will only change the memory pointed by local a and leak memory
...
}

int main()
{
  int *a;
  int cnt = 0;
  read(&a, &cnt);
  ...
}
```

What is happening you’re giving the address to the pointer `a` to the function and then in the function you’re immediately overwriting it with the memory allocation. Matter this the `a` in the function and `a` in the main are *completely separate entities*. If you then allocate memory for `*a` you’re only storing that in the *local* `a` and the main `a` will remain pointing to whatever it happened to be. So it is uninitialized and causes undefined behavior.

So remove the line `a = malloc(sizeof(int))` and your code will properly affect the main `a` also.

You also have to use `*a` for everything in `read`, including `scanf` and `while`. So it might be better to make the function handle allocation and return a pointer as was suggested in another answer.

Also note you should check `realloc` for return values so you won’t leak memory or crash there and you should use `sizeof(int*)` when allocating a pointer, no matter if size of `int` and `int*` were the same. It looks clearer.

Comment: That’s true, adding that. Thanks @M.M

Answer (score 0):

You can pattern your function along the POSIX [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) function.

The pattern is very simple. Your function receives a reference to the pointer (i.e., a pointer to a pointer) used for the data, resized dynamically; and a pointer to the size allocated to that pointer. It will return the number of elements read to the array.

If you were reading `double`s rather than `int`s, and wished to read all doubles from the input until end-of-input (either end of file, if redirected from a file, or until the user types a non-number and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or until the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the beginning of the line), the code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t read_doubles(double **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr, FILE *in)
{
    double *data;      /* A local copy of the pointer */
    size_t  used = 0;  /* Number of doubles in data */
    size_t  size;      /* Number of doubles allocated for data */

    /* Sanity checks against NULL pointers. */
    if (!dataptr || !sizeptr || !in) {
        errno = EINVAL; /* "Invalid parameter" */
        return 0;
    }

    /* If *dataptr is NULL, or *sizeptr is zero,
       there is no memory allocated yet. */
    if (*dataptr != NULL && *sizeptr > 0) {
        data = *dataptr;
        size = *sizeptr;
    } else {
        data = NULL;
        size = 0;
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
    }

    while (1) {

        /* Ensure there is room in the data. */
        if (used >= size) {
            /* Need to allocate more.
               Note: we have a copy of (data) in (*dataptr),
               and of (size) in (*sizeptr). */

            /* Reallocation policy. This one is simple,
               reallocating in fixed-size chunks, but
               better ones are well known: you probably
               wish to ensure the size is at least some
               sensible minimum (maybe a thousand or so),
               then double the size up to a few million,
               then increase the size in fixed-size chunks
               of a few million, in a real-world application. */
            size = used + 500;

            /* Note: malloc(size) and realloc(NULL, size)
               are equivalent; no need to check for NULL. */
            data = realloc(data, size * sizeof data[0]);
            if (!data) {
                /* Reallocation failed, but the old data
                   pointer in (*dataptr) is still valid,
                   it isn't lost. Return an error. */
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return 0;
            }

            /* Reallocation succeeded; update the originals,
               that are visible to the caller. */
            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        /* Read one more element, if possible.
           Note: "&(data[used])" and "data+used"
           are completely equivalent expressions.
        */
        if (fscanf(input, " %lf", data + used) != 1)
            break; /* No more input, or not a number. */

        /* Yes, read a new data element. */
        used++;
    }

    /* If we encountered a true read error,
       return an error. */
    if (ferror(input)) {
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Not an error; there just weren't more
       data, or the data was not a number.
    */

    /* Normally, programs do not set errno
       except in case of an error. However,
       here, used==0 just means there was no
       data, it does not indicate an error per se.
       For simplicity, because we know no error
       has occurred, we just set errno=0 here,
       rather than check if used==0 and only then
       set errno to zero.
       This also means it is safe to examine errno
       after a call to this function, no matter what
       the return value is. errno will be zero if no
       errors have occurred, and nonzero in error cases.
    */

    errno = 0;
    return used;
}
```

The `<errno.h>` was included for the library to expose `errno`, and `<string.h>` for `strerror()`. These are both standard C.

However, the [error constants](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) I used above, `EINVAL`, `ENOMEM`, and `EIO`, are only defined by POSIXy systems, and might not exist in all systems. That is okay; you can just pick any smallish nonzero values and use them instead, because the function always sets `errno`. In that case, however, you need to check each of them and print the appropriate error message for each. In my case, all the systems I use define those three error codes for me, and I can just use `strerror(errno)` to convert the code to a standard error message (`Invalid argument`, `Not enough space`, and `Input/output error`, respectively, in non-localized programs).

Using a function defined like above, is very simple:

```
int main(void)
{
    double *data = NULL; /* NULL for "Not allocated yet" */
    size_t  size = 0;    /* 0 for "Not allocated yet" */
    size_t  used;

    size_t  i; /* Just a loop variable. */

    used = read_doubles(&data, &size, stdin);
    if (!used) {
        /* No data read. Was it an actual error, or just no data? */
        if (errno)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading standard input: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "No numbers in standard input!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read %zu numbers from standard input.\n", used);
    printf("(The dynamically allocated array has room for %zu.)\n", size);

    for (i = 0; i < used; i++)
        printf("    %f\n", data[i]);

    /* Array no longer needed, so we can free it.
       Explicitly NULLing and zeroing them means
       we can safely reuse them later, if we were
       to extend this program. So, it's not necessary
       to clear them this way, but it is a good practice
       considering it makes long-term maintenance easier. */
    free(data);
    data = NULL;
    size = 0;
    used = 0;

    /* This version of the program has nothing more to do. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Essentially, you just set the pointer you supply the address of to `NULL`, and the size you supply the address of also to `0`, before the call to indicate no array has been dynamically allocated yet.  There is no need to `malloc()` an initial array; `realloc(NULL, size)` is completely safe, and does exactly what `malloc(size)` does. Indeed, I often write code that has no `malloc()` anywhere in it, and use only `realloc()`.

Note that the above code snippets are untested, so there might be typos in them. (And I did choose to use `double`s instead of `int`s and a different end-of-input condition, to ensure you don't just copy-paste the code and use as-is, without reading and understanding it first.) If you find or suspect you found any, let me know in a comment, and I'll check.

Also note that the above code snippets are long only because I tried to write descriptive comments -- literally most of the "code" in them is comments.  Writing descriptive comments -- those that describe the *intent* of the code, and not just what the code actually does; the latter is easy to read from the code itself, but the former is what you or others later reading the code *need* to know, to check if the code is sound or buggy --, is very hard, and even after over two decades, I'm still trying to get better at it.

If you like writing code, I do warmly recommend you start practicing writing good, intent-describing comments right away, rather than battle with it for decades like I have.  It is surprising how much good comments, and occasionally a good nights sleep to review the code with fresh pair of eyes, helps.